# How do you know when to understand the Hebrew word עלום (olam) as "eternal" or simply a long duration?

Tags: hebrew, psalms

In [Gen. 9:16](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Gen&c=9&t=KJV#s=t_conc_9016), עלום is translated as "everlasting" in reference to the covenant of the rainbow:

> וְהָיְתָה הַקֶּשֶׁת בֶּעָנָן וּרְאִיתִיהָ לִזְכֹּר בְּרִית עוֹלָם בֵּין אֱלֹהִים וּבֵין כָּל נֶפֶשׁ חַיָּה בְּכָל בָּשָׂר אֲשֶׁר עַל הָאָרֶץ
>
> And the bow shall be in the cloud; and I will look upon it, that I may remember the everlasting covenant between God and every living creature of all flesh that is upon the earth. (KJV)

In [Dan. 12:2](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Dan&c=12&t=KJV#s=t_conc_862002), עלום is translated as "eternal" ("everlasting") in reference to the life received by those who awaken from their sleep (i.e., in the resurrection):

> וְרַבִּים מִיְּשֵׁנֵי אַדְמַת עָפָר יָקִיצוּ אֵלֶּה לְחַיֵּי עוֹלָם וְאֵלֶּה לַחֲרָפוֹת לְדִרְאוֹן עוֹלָם
>
> And many of them that sleep in the dust of the earth shall awake, some to everlasting life, and some to shame and everlasting contempt. (KJV)

However, in [Psa. 143:3](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Psa&c=143&t=KJV#s=t_conc_621003), should it be understood as "eternity" or simply a long duration?

> כִּי רָדַף אוֹיֵב נַפְשִׁי דִּכָּא לָאָרֶץ חַיָּתִי הוֹשִׁבַנִי בְמַחֲשַׁכִּים כְּמֵתֵי עוֹלָם
>
> For the enemy hath persecuted my soul; he hath smitten my life down to the ground; he hath made me to dwell in darkness, as those that have been long dead. (KJV)

Comment: There is no way to definitely determine according to a rule. You have to rely on context.

Comment: Just to offer some advice, a great Christian commentary on the Old Testament is by Keil and Delitzsch (that is, if you are a Christian). You should read what they have to say on this verse:

http://www.studylight.org/com/kdo/view.cgi?bk=18&ch=143

Comment: Interesting question!  I'd encourage you to post it on the [Judaism stackexchange site](http://mi.yodeya.com) in addition to here  - they know the Old Testament well.

Comment: I agree with **H3br3wHamm3r81** about the context. In fact, negative expressions convey the concept of something being eternal way better than such adjectives like "eternal" or "everlasting": "...the Creator of the ends of the earth, fainteth **not**, **neither** is weary" (Isa 40:28), "...before me there was **no** God formed, **neither** shall there be after me" (Isa 43:10), "But thou art the same, and thy years shall have **no** end" (Psalms 102:27)

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of semantics, the Hebrew word עלם ('olam) means something more like the English words 'age' or 'era', in the sense of a distant time period.

עלם is occasionally translated as 'everlasting' or 'eternal', with a meaning of 'age-enduring'. For example, some passages describe hills or mountains as עלם (Genesis 49.26; Deuteronomy 33.15; Habakkuk 3.6), because from the view of the writers, mountains endure countless ages; from human perspective, they are 'eternal'.

So as @H3br3wHamm3r81 [said above](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7499/how-do-you-know-when-to-understand-the-hebrew-word-olam-as-eternal-or-s#comment14690_7499), how עלם should be translated is entirely dependent on context. Relatively speaking, few words have an absolute one-to-one translation in any given language.